# VSCODE snippets : Force intellisense after only one character pressed

Tags: visual-studio-code, code-snippets, prefix

I'm new to VSCode and I want to test it to compare with my sublime text configuration. I want to create a very simple snippet that allow me to write ruby code `<%= %>` when I only press <kbd><</kbd> key.

Here is my snippet's code :

```json
    "My snippet": {
        "prefix": "<",
        "body": [
            "<%= $1 %>"
        ],
        "description": "My snippet"
    }
```

So this code works but I have to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> in my file to show the IntelliSense list (with my snippet). I just want to press <kbd><</kbd> and <kbd>Tab</kbd> to complete this, not to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> always.

Do you know if there's a configuration to do it ?

Thanx

Comment: I'm interested in the opposite. My vscode provides suggestion after the first character, which I find annoying. I'd rather it do that only after the third character, but I was unable to find such a setting.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is a long time since your question, but I think it may help others.

In settings you need to enable `editor.tabCompletion`, then you can press <kbd>tab</kbd> even if there is no IntelliSense.

Answer (score 3):

To have the snippet auto-injected into the VS Code Editor when you press `Tab` after the prefix (even this is only one character), you need to set the `editor.tabCompletion` setting to `onlySnippets`, neither `off` nor `on`.

```json
    "editor.tabCompletion": "onlySnippets",
```

personally, I think this is a very strange behavior, and that, in theory, with the value `on` the `tabCompletion` option should also work. but somehow this option works like that, at least for me.

Answer (score 1):

There are two configuration values you can set in order to let VSCode show suggestions and snippets immediately.

```json
    // Controls if quick suggestions should show up or not while typing
    "editor.quickSuggestions": true, 

    // Controls the delay in ms after which quick suggestions will show up
    "editor.quickSuggestionsDelay": 0,
```

With this setup suggestions popup as soon as possible.

Comment: Thanx for your response. I tried your 2 lines in my settings, but when i press "<" and "tab" nothing appears (my snippet no works). Press "<" and "ctrl + space" works always but this is not my need :)

When I specify a letter in my snippet, for example, "prefix": "p" instead of "prefix": "<", it works when I press "p + tab" in my file.

Comment: @John hello John, i have the problem that same you, have you solved it yet?